# proper use of 'newData' in Firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Can anyone provide guidance on the correct way to use 'newData' in Firebase rules?  I realise it cannot be used for '.read' (for obvious reasons) but I've also noticed that the examples provided by [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/) are always using 'newData' within validation rules.  For example, under 'hasChild(childPath)', Google's guide shows:

```
".validate": "newData.hasChild('name')"
```

I've also found this [other link](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json) from GitHub.  I've found this to be very helpful too, when working out how to put robust rules together.  I've noticed though that 'newData' is used mostly under 'validate' and seldom with 'write'.  The only 'newData' example I've found with 'write' rules is from the second link

```
".write": "!newData.exists()"
```

I wonder if there is a reason for this. Are there limitations to how 'newData' can be used within 'write' rules?  For example, will the following always work?  My experiments indicate it doesn't but maybe I've missed something.

```
".write": "newData.hasChild('name')"
```

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

The `newData` variable is available and can be used effectively in with `.write` and `.validate` rules. If you have a good use-case for it in your write rules, go for it!

I typically use `.write` rules to ensure the user has proper permission to write to the location. That permission doesn't usually depend on the new data, but purely on the location and on existing data in other places

`.validate` rules on the other hand are used to validate that the new data is structured in the way your app requires and that the values are allowed. So hence the more common use of `newData` here.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  Your answer rules out some issues.  I've been puzzling over this one for a while now.  You're right about using {.write} for permissions.  I've been looking for a way to compare a new data entry with a list of users allowed to make a public announcement.  The rule looks something like this {".write": "root.child('public').child(newData.child('user').val()).exists()"}.  Any tips how to troubleshoot a bit more?

Comment: If you're having trouble making your code work, include the use-case and the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question please. In this case that should include a snippet of the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots), which you can get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Ok.  I think the question is still valid though as I'm trying to keep the issues as simple as possible.  The examples I've found don't seem to use newData much for .write, so I wondered if there are any major restrictions.  The JSON is very simple: "public" : {
    "user1" : true }}